# xscreensaver doesn't stop fadeout correctly

Tags: x11, xorg, screen-lock, xscreensaver

I have xscreensaver set to blank my screen, with a 5 second fade duration. When user input happens during this fadeout, the following happens:

1. *screen starts fading*
2. Image freezes, only fading updates
3. *user input happens*
4. Fading continues until finished
5. Screen goes blank, then unblanks immediately

What I would expect to happen is:

1. *screen starts fading*
2. *user input happens*
3. Fading stops, screen is never blanked

Is this possible using xscreensaver?

Comment: You could send a bug report about this, see [here](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/bugs.html).

Comment: Note that there is one second time during which user input is ignored to avoid accidental deactivating of screensaver. This is independent of the fade setting.

Comment: The former does happen only, if you run `xscreensaver-command` in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "grace period" setting called [`lockTimeout`](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html) which controls how long the user can interrupt once the screensaver starts (independently of fading out, it seems). Simply [set it to the same as your `fadeSeconds` value](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/6f639a5d93442368f854dbcaca106024423ddd6d) for a less surprising user experience:

```
xscreensaver.fadeSeconds:   0:00:10
xscreensaver.lockTimeout:   00:00:10
```

Comment: In my experience the setting does not work during fading out. Besides, it does not have any effect, if `lock` is set to False.