# How to force xscreensaver-command -lock to blank immediately?

Tags: xscreensaver

Related to [xscreensaver doesn't stop fadeout correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/362116), I've set up a [`suspend@$USER` service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Suspend.2Fresume_service_files) which runs `/usr/bin/xscreensaver-command -lock` to lock the screen when closing the laptop lid. The article states:

> As screen lockers may return before the screen is "locked", the screen may flash on resuming from suspend. Adding a small delay via ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 1 helps prevent this.

Unfortunately it's not this simple with XScreenSaver - it will take until `xscreensaver.lockTimeout` to fully blank the screen. Since this process is interrupted (by sleeping) on resume the screen shows up slightly greyed (as it would be after a second of fade-out) and stays like that seemingly until the 10 seconds are up (fading seems to stop working), at which point the password dialogue shows up. Since I've set `xscreensaver.lockTimeout` I have to make sure to sleep longer than the setting to avoid showing the screen contents on resume. This is brittle since I need to keep the settings in sync, and makes suspend take longer. So **how can I force XScreenSaver to lock *immediately*,** ignoring `xscreensaver.lockTimeout`?

Comment: Did you mean `fadeSeconds` setting (and not `lockTimeout`) ?

Comment: The manual says `xscreensaver-command -lock` does not care about lockTimeout resource.